# Anonymous SQL/PL Block with multiple selects and inserts

Tags: oracle11g

How can I run this SQL PL block and insert at the same time.  I tried and its not working at all.  I am new in the coding, just got off school and this is my first job, please help me.

```
Select a.col1,a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col5 
from Table1 a 
Join Table2 b on a.col1 = b.col1

insert into mass table col1, col3, col4 
     values ('1', '3', '4') 
insert into Report Table col2, col5  
     values('10','20')
insert into Check_log table col1, col2, col3, col4, col 5 error msg, successful, duplicate  
     values('1','3', '4','10', '20','failed to load', '', '')

Select b.col1,b.col2, c.col3, c.col4, c.col5  
from Table1 b 
Join Table2 c on a.col2 = b.col2

insert into mass table col1, col3, col4 
       values ('2', '80') 
insert into Report Table col3, col5 
       values('3','20')
insert into Check_log table col1, col2, col3, col4, col 5 error msg, successful, duplicate  
       values('1','3', '4','10', '20','', 'Successful', '')


Select f.col1,d.col2, d.col3, f.col4, d.col5  
from Table1 d 
Join Table2 f on f.col3 = d.col3

insert into mass table col1, col1, col4 
       values ('1', '4') 
insert into Report Table col2, col3  
       values('10','3')
insert into Check_log table col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 error msg, successful, duplicate 
       values('1','3', '4','10', '20','', '', 'duplicate')
```

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO table_name ( column_name1, column_name2 ) VALUES ( value1, value2 );` There is no `TABLE` keyword in the statement and you need brackets around the column names.

Comment: Also, what are the `SELECT` statements supposed to be doing? Are you trying to use the values returned to create dynamic SQL statements or do your tables really have names like `col1` rather than more descriptive names?

Comment: I am trying to create a dynamic SQL statements  and yes the tables have the names like   Table1 = Accounts table with account numbers, Table2 = Cus_info with customer information such as ssn, names, address, dob, age, gender etc.  Thank you for your assistance.